# Автоматическое заполнение инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите в реализации задачи. Необходимо реализовать автоматическое наполнение инфоблока новостей. Покурил мануалы и API, готового решения естественно не нашел, попробовал сваять свой кусок кода ну и естественно нихрена не работает, может быть найдутся люди кто сталкивался с такой задачей.

```
$nameNews       = "Тест";
$dateNews       = 20.01.2012;
$contentNews    = "Полное описание"

$new_el = new CIBlockElement;

        $arLoadArray = Array(
            "MODIFIED_BY"       => $USER->GetID(), // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
            "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
            "IBLOCK_ID"         => 95, // ID инфоблока
            "NAME"              => $nameNews,
            "ACTIVE"            => "Y",            // активен
            "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM"  => $dateNews,       //начало активности
            "PREVIEW_TEXT"      => $nameNews,
            "PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE" => 'html',
            "DETAIL_TEXT"       => $contentNews,
            "DETAIL_TEXT_TYPE"  => 'html'
        );

if($PRODUCT_ID = $new_el->Add($arLoadProductArray))
  echo "New ID: ".$PRODUCT_ID;
else
  echo "Error: ".$new_el->LAST_ERROR;
```

При обращении к файлу **Ошибка HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error): При попытке сервера выполнить запрос возникла неожиданная ситуация.**

Comment: а не проще посмотреть базу и без монстра Битрикса обойтись ?

Comment: конечно, проще, полностью согласен, но делаю функционал не для себя, а для кОООнтент-менджеров :)которые работают только с инфоблоками

Comment: @Ale_x не ну представьте, точку с запятой забыл поставить, вот смех ))))) все работает